# Is there a way to detect if an audio device is muted in Node.js (Mac)?

Tags: javascript, macos, audio, core-audio

I'm looking for a library (preferred in js) to detect if a device is muted or not (and also what's it's volume, etc) in Mac OS, and couldn't find any.
The library I need should probably use a lower level language to make this kind of job, so I tried to find a c++ sdk for that purpose, and saw `CoreAudio` might be a good fit. Is there a chance no one ever wrapped this sdk with higher level language? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It looks like it will fit your needs.  https://github.com/LinusU/node-loudness